# How to fetch the value in dictionary by checking the key mapped in the dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary is below

```
my = {
  "1": {
    "exclude": 'A,B',
    "column": "value",
    "output": "Out1",
    "Out1": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  },
  "2": {
    "exclude": 'None',
    "column": "value",
    "output": "Out2",
    "Out1": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  }
}
```

- I need to check column key value (if lower(my[column])) == lower(value)
- I have `exclude_list = ['A','B','C']`
- I need to the exclude key, if exclude is 'A' check the `exclude_list = ['A','B','C']`  take the value `B,C`. If the exclude key is 'A,B' take the value `C` as shown in the example.
- I need to check the `output` key if `output` key is `Out1` then fetch value of `Out1` and mapped to `EndOutput`

Expected Out

```
{'1': {'exclude': ['C'], 'EndOutput': 'Cost'},
 '2': {'exclude': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'EndOutput': 'Rev'}}

exclude_list = ['A','B','C']
for k,v in my.items():
    if v['column'].lower() == 'value'.lower:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over keys 1,2 .. N with `for e in my:` and then calculate exclude with help of `set()` difference as

and extract things like this

```
 exc = set(['A','B','C']) - set(my[e]["exclude"].split(",") if len(my[e]["exclude"].split(",")) else [] )
```

next you can take value of `out1` or `out2` depending on the value of `output` as

```
my[e][my[e]["output"]]
```

Insert in new dictionary as

```
newdict[e] = {'exclude': list(exc) ,'EndOutput':my[e][my[e]["output"]]}
```

**Overall**, this is how you can iterate

```
newdict = {}
for e in my:
     if my[e]['column'].lower() == 'value':
             exc = set(['A','B','C']) - set(my[e]["exclude"].split(",") if len(my[e]["exclude"].split(",")) else [] )
             newdict[e] = {'exclude': list(exc) ,'EndOutput':my[e][my[e]["output"]]}
```

printing newdict will produce this output

```
'1': {'EndOutput': 'Cost', 'exclude': ['C'] },
'2': {'EndOutput': 'Rev', 'exclude': ['A', 'B', 'C'] }}
```

Comment: I have one query if my dictionary is not having `exclude` key  for one one dictonary i am getting key error `my = {
  "3": {
    "column": "value",
    "output": "Out1",
    "Out1": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  },
  "4": {
    "exclude": 'None',
    "column": "value",
    "output": "Out2",
    "Out1": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  }
}

Comment: I think you have missed the condition I need to check column key value (if lower(my[column])) == lower(value)

Comment: what you need to do if column value is not equal?

Comment: I dont want that dictionary let say for key 1 there column == something then my output `{ 2': {'EndOutput': 'Rev', 'exclude': ['A', 'B', 'C'] }}`

Comment: I have updated the answer, is "value" the constant string that you want to match for every dictionary?

Comment: Yes the value is the contant

Comment: okay let me know if updated answer works,also feel free to accept it as answer and upvote if it helped